# Bringing Homemade Trail Mix to Hawaii Given Food Import Restrictions

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, hawaii

Because I have hungry, snacky, picky-eater kids, I make homemade trail mix ahead of every vacation. Aside from the obligatory candy, it generally contains almonds, peanuts, cashews, raisins, and sweetened cranberries. None of these things should be able to germinate if dropped on the ground.

**Question: has anyone tried taking any of these ingredients (almonds, peanuts, cashews, raisins, crushed and sweetened cranberries) into Hawaii? If so, were they permitted or refused? OR does anyone know the appropriate Hawaiian agency so I can contact them ahead of time and just ask them?**

Comment: into Hawaii from the continental US, or from another country?

Comment: I'm suspect that your kids wouldn't be terribly bothered if you just brought along the "obligatory candy" and left out all those things that the agricultural inspectors are concerned about.  ;-)

Comment: @KateGregory Sorry, yes, from mainland USA to Hawaii. That's why I included the USA tag as well as the Hawaii tag but that really expects an unfair degree of mind reading to get what I was trying to express with that.

Comment: Conclusion: In the end, we decided to abandon the trail mix as my husband and I have begun a no-sugar-added/no-artificial-sweeteners lifestyle change and my son was just found to have a mouthful of cavities from sipping canned sweet tea, so he doesn't get candy and raisins either. Trail mix became moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Domestically**

As per State of Hawaii, Plant Industry Division [TRAVELING FROM THE U.S. MAINLAND TO HAWAII](http://hdoa.hawaii.gov/pi/pq/travel-shipping-information/traveling-from-the-u-s-mainland-to-hawai%CA%BBi/)

> **FOOD PRODUCTS**
>
> In general, foods that are cooked, canned, frozen or
>   commercially processed and/or packaged are allowed to be transported
>   to Hawaii, as long as the product is arriving from within the U.S.
>
> Frozen or chilled meats are also allowed to be transported to Hawaii
>   as long as the meat originated from within the U.S.
>
> Manufactured food products are not required to be declared or
>   inspected.

My advice would be to bring the packaged ingredients in your luggage and make up the trail mix when you get there.

If you need some during the flight I'd only take along enough mixed trail mix for the flight itself in case you are asked to dump it at the airport.

**Internationally**

If you are arriving from another country, then it becomes a US CBP issue and the relevant link is: [Travelers bringing food into the U.S. for personal use](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/3619/kw/food).  That site explicitly lists a large number of allowed/disallowed products.  So check off your ingredients to see what is/isn't allowed.

Comment: Another option would of course be to buy the ingredients after arriving in Hawaii.

Comment: @phoog I thought of that, but it may be cheaper to buy them on the mainland.

Comment: I suppose it probably would be.  Still, the price difference might be small enough that other considerations would control the decision.  For example, if I were staying somewhere with a kitchen and planning to shop for food anyway, I wouldn't want to carry the extra stuff on the flight.  But if I weren't, and I had a very busy schedule in Hawaii, I wouldn't want to have to take time away from the beach or whatever for shopping.  Either consideration would outweigh a few dollars in savings.

Comment: @phoog Don't forget the picky eating kids on the multi-hour plane ride!

Comment: Of course.  One would need some food for them either way.

Comment: We have only five days and are not staying somewhere with a kitchen, so I'd have to beg room service for a very large bowl to mix in. But the real thing here is that I don't want to have to see the inside of a grocery store, let alone a Trader Joes (if Kauai even has one) to get the nuts 'n' stuff. I emailed the Hawaiian Department of Agriculture which seemed to be the ultimate agency responsible for what comes into the state. They may or may not answer, but I'd like to think my query at least gave them a good laugh.

Comment: @SnappingShrimp Kauai's a small island, so you will likely go past a supermarket no matter where you go to do touristy things.   And even supermarkets can be interesting experiences as you will see things for sale that you won't normally see at home (like POG juice, although I may be mistaken on that)

Comment: This is a very useful answer with official sources that were useful to me and will hopefully be useful to other anxious and detail-oriented people.